# Compile embedded lua in C

Tags: c, lua

Hey everyone I found this code that embeds Lua in C and I cannot figure out how to get GCC to compile it.  I have Lua installed, but how do I link the Lua libraries?

Here is the code I found:

```
            #include <stdio.h>
            #include "lua.h"
            #include "lualib.h"
            #include "lauxlib.h"

            /* lua interpreter */
            lua_State* l;

            int main () {
            int dofile;

            /* initialize lua */
            l = lua_open();

            /* load lua libraries */
            luaL_openlibs(l);

            /* run the hello.lua script */
            dofile = luaL_dofile(l, "hello.lua");

            if (dofile == 0) {
            /* call foo */
            lua_getglobal(l,"foo");
            lua_call(l,0,0);
            }
            else {
            printf("Error, unable to run hello.lua\n");
            }

            /* cleanup Lua */
            lua_close(l);

            return 0;
            }
```

How do I get this to compile?

I am trying this command to compile

```
gcc -o embed_hello -L/users/etrosclair/Downloads/lua-5.1.4 -I/users/etrosclair/Downloads/lua-5.1.4 luaTest.c
```

Here is the error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_luaL_newstate", referenced from:
      _main in ccF0995Q.o
  "_luaL_openlibs", referenced from:
      _main in ccF0995Q.o
  "_luaL_loadfile", referenced from:
      _main in ccF0995Q.o
  "_lua_pcall", referenced from:
      _main in ccF0995Q.o
  "_lua_getfield", referenced from:
      _main in ccF0995Q.o
  "_lua_call", referenced from:
      _main in ccF0995Q.o
  "_lua_close", referenced from:
      _main in ccF0995Q.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

All the lua libraries and headers are in the lua-5.1.4 folder the .o files are also in there too.

Thanks

Thanks

Comment: probably something like `-llua` on the command line. Why don't you show us some errors?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Depends if you want it statically or dynamically compiled.

For static, add -llua  (or lua5.1 or lua51; depending on your setup)

Comment: It also works for shared libraries, so OP should try adding -llua, -llua5.1 and -llua-5.1 to the command line.

Comment: if available on your system, you could use `gcc -o hello hello.o $(pkg-config --libs lua)`